# creating json from DOM elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, dom

If I have the following DOM elements

```
<div class="item">content1</div>
<div class="item">content2</div>
```

how, using jQuery and Javascript, do I construct a JSON object like the following?

```
[{ 
'classname': 'item',
'content': 'content1'
}
{
'classname': 'item',
'content': 'content2'
}]
```

Any recommended further reading?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Sometimes the best representation of the data is the data itself.

Comment: Consider keeping your data in a MVC model, not the DOM...

Comment: I'm trying to construct a JSON table like that used here: http://links.sourceforge.net/timeline/js/examples/example17_json_data.html But instead of writing the html in the json object directly, I wanted to write the html in the DOM, and _then_ construct the json object. Is this the best way of going about it?

Comment: This is the object he uses in the example, but it seems messy to write the html as such. ta = [
          {
            'start': new Date(2010,7,23),
            'content': 'Conversation<br><img src="img/comments-icon.png" style="width:32px; height:32px;">'
          },

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var data = $('div.item').map(function(){
    return {
        classname: 'item',
        content: $(this).text()
    };
}).get();
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nDE7e/

Comment: Nice. What are the merits of doing it this way over using .each() ?

Comment: `.map` will return you an array, instead of having to make one beforehand.

Comment: Nice approach.
It looks like you can get rid about the last .get().

Comment: @aschuler: The `.get()` is there so that you're returned an array.  Otherwise, you're returned a jQuery object.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/24JjD/

```
var datas = [{ 
    'classname': 'item',
    'content': 'content1'
    }, {
    'classname': 'item',
    'content': 'content2'
    }
];

$.each(datas, function(key, value) {
    $('body').append('<div class="'+value.classname+'">'+value.content+'</div>');
});​
```

Correct answer :

http://jsfiddle.net/tS9r5/

```
var datas = [];

$('div.item').each(function() {
   var data = { 
       classname: this.className, 
       content: $(this).text()
   };
   datas.push(data);
});

console.log(datas);
```

​

​

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the item divs and add objects to an array.

```
var items = new Array();

$("div.item").each(function() {
   var item = {classname: this.className, content: $(this).text()};
   items.push(item);
});
```