# Create JSON from Dom elements in a `div`

Tags: jquery, html, json

I need to get all the elements inside a `div`, which could be multiple `inputs`, `checkboxs`, `radiobuttons` etc, and convert the `id` or `name` and `value` of it to a `JSON` readable format.

I've tried to use a modified version of the [the following SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932469/creating-json-from-dom-elements-using-jquery), which resulted in the following:

```
var data = $('#item').map(function() {
    return {
        content: $(this).val()
    };
}).get();

console.log(data);
```

---

```
<div id="item">
    <input class="item" id="test" value="data" />
</div>
```

But it doesn't return any value.

Comment: use `serializeArray()` then convert the result to a object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running your `map` access the div (which doesn't have a value as it is not a form control), not the input inside it.

You probably want `'#item :input'` are your selector.

Comment: Update: Any idea how it would work on a `select`, I've used `.children()` instead of `:input`

Comment: Got it: `selectedText: $(this).find(":selected").text()`

Comment: @NewAmbition — You really don't need to do that that. The code you already had will get values from select elements: http://jsfiddle.net/4HV5v/

Comment: I'm an idiot... The first option didn't have a `val` to it, so I thought there was an error.. Your solution works :)

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
var map = {};

    $("#item").children().each(function (i, element)
       {
          map[$(element).attr("id")] = $(element).val();
        }
     );
```