# generate JSONobject from bootstrapHTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, html, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic

I'm building a very simple FormBuilder where the user creates textfields and can change the order of them. All the HTML is added dynamically with jQuery.

Now i want to generate a JSONobject based on the html.

This is an example of a HTML output:

```
<div id="komp1" class="in">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Lägg till element</label>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
         <select class="form-control" id="komp1select">
            <option>...</option>
            <option>Textfält</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Textfält#1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLabel1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLabel1"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputValue1" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Value</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue1" placeholder=""></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
         <h3 class="panel-title">Textfält#2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLabel2" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Label</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLabel2"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputValue2" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Value</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue2" placeholder=""></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to loop through each panel element inside of the "komp1" div. For each panel i want to create an object with the type input, the ID and the values from my two inputfields. The output should look similar to this:

```
{"elements":[{"type":"input","id":"value1","label":"","value":""},{"type":"input","id":"value2","label":"","value":""}]}
```

How can i approach this with jQuery?

Comment: You should be able to use an approach similar to the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932469/creating-json-from-dom-elements-using-jquery. If you have specific questions, show us your code and describe the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Didn't test it, just a quick idea:

```
var inputs = $("#komp1.panel").find( "input" );
var jsonObj = {elements:[]};

for (var i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++){
    jsonObj["elements"].push({type: "input",value: inputs[i].value, id: inputs[i].attr("id")})
}

var json = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```